# Maven cannot access (existing) pom file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I am trying to compile a `java` project with `maven`. 
I have tried it with the right `click on pom file`  > `Maven` > `Maven Install` in `Eclipse` (m2eclipse connector)

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) ... 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:pom:1.0 from/to maven-central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/)
```

Then I tried it in command prompt with `mvn clean compile`, but I got this screenshot:

[image]

It seems to me that `maven` can not access the `maven-filtering-1.0 file`, even though I can access the pom file in the browser using the same URL. 
I am new to `maven` and have no idea how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you perhaps behind a proxy?

Comment: No, I am not behind a proxy.

Comment: Screenshots of command line output are *much* harder to read than a formatted copy/paste of the data.

Comment: @Atticus The output gives an other impression.

Comment: @khmarbaise: the sysadmins give another impression :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Here is what I did. It might help sembody else facing the same difficulties.

I simply deleted everything I could in my local repository (~/.m2/repository). Then I ran the `mvn install` and everything worked fine.

Again, I did not have a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

If you're behind a proxy you can add a blurb to your `~/.m2/setting.xml`

```
<settings>
  ....
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>Proxy name</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>your.proxy.hostname.or.IP</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <!-- omit these auth params if not needed: -->
      <username>domain\\username</username>
      <password>123456</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1|...</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

if not, try talking `telnet` or `wget` the POM from the command line:

```
wget http://repo.maven.apache.org/..../maven-filtering-1.0.pom
```

and try to determine what goes wrong from there.

Cheers,